# When accessing resources by property name is it possible to change which ResourceManager is used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources

I want to use a custom ResourceProvider but still have the benefit of strongly typed resource names. It seems though that in my view if I access the resource property directly like so:

```
@Html.Raw(UIText.Header)
```

Then the text is read directly from the resx file and doesn't go through my custom provider factory which is defined in the web.config.

```
@Html.Raw(HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("UIText.resx", "Header").ToString())
```

Works fine but has the down-side of being stringly typed. I have created an extension method which wraps this but its still quite ugly:

```
@Html.ResourceText(() => UIText.Header)
```

So, is there a way to use the resource properties directly but have them route through a custom provider without having to create our own `ResXFileCodeGenerator`?

Answer (score 0):

Would a static class that holds strings work for you? I've made a T4 template file that looks at my .resx and generates this static class *automagically*.

This is the result of the T4 template compilation:

```
public static class ResourceStrings {
    public const string AddAttachments = @"AddAttachments";
    public const string button_create = @"button_create";
    public const string button_delete = @"button_delete";
    public const string button_details = @"button_details";
    public const string button_display = @"button_display";
    ...
}
```

I use it my ASP.NET MVC attributes to classes like this:

```
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(i18n),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourceStrings.Client_VatNo_length_validation_msg)]
    public string VatNo;

    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (i18n),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = ResourceStrings.Client_BaseIdentNr_length_validation_msg)]
    public string BaseIdentNr;
```

Hopefully I didn't miss it completely;)